# Dreamviewer is not showing any syntax error in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I have ubuntu 14.04 and i have installed Dreamviewer8 software through wine on my Development team System and they are facing issue in dreamviewer 8 no syntax error is showing in dreamveiwer 8 is their any other editor like dreamveiwer so that i can install that software

Answer (score 0):

Have you try bluefish? Maybe you can use [Brackets (by Adobe)](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/install-brackets-in-ubuntu-via-ppa-open.html) or [Atom (by Github)](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-atom-text-editor-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) or [Sublime Text 3](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/sublime-text-3-ubuntu-ppa-now-available.html). if you use Dreamweaver for web development I suggest Brackets if you use PSD... if not, I like Sublime Text 3, give a try.

I think maybe Dreamweaver not showing syntax errors because needs windows libraries to work properly.